# How to allow invoking an AWS Lambda function only from EC2 instances inside a VPC

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am struggling with understanding how I can easily invoke my lambda function from an EC2 instance within a VPC.

I think I have a quite common problem but strangely enough I didn't found anything specific for this "pattern".

I have a Python application in an EC2 instance and I would like to launch heavy processing functions in parallel using Lambda functions and keep the EC2 quite light-weight.

Ideally, the Lambda function could be invoked only from within the VPC (only from my EC2 instances).

My understanding is that I have to create an API gateway (or add an API endpoint to the Lambda function) but I don't understand how to invoke this function from the EC2 (I am trying to use HTTP requests without success) nor how to set permissions.

I used a trigger in the function to set-up the API gateway and I am using the corresponding link for requests.

Comment: You don't need API Gateway for this, just invoke the function directly using the AWS SDK for Python (Boto). Use the IAM role assigned to the EC2 instance to allow the instance to invoke the function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are various ways, *other* than API Gateway, to invoke Lambda functions. The one most relevant to your use case would be the `Invoke` API. You can find the official documentation [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_Invoke.html) and the Boto library's, in case you are using Boto, [here](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/lambda.html#Lambda.Client.invoke).

Also, as mentioned in a comment on the question, you can assign an IAM role to the EC2 instances that allows them to `Invoke` the Lambda function.

Comment: I am trying to use boto3 but without success. I am using a python3 console from my ec2 instance. I set up the IAM role "AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole" for the ec2 instance and tried to use the invoke function getting as an error: "ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDeniedException)"...could you add a simple examble on how it should be set-up? Thanks

Comment: Solved, it was the wrong policy, I had to include the action invokeFunction that is in the policy AWS lambda role. Now I managed to make it work thanks.